# How can I select a particular relation code details if 3 relation codes are available in the select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query which has the following result. I want to get the result in the preference guarantor, executive, owner.

1. if 3 relation code is present result should be of the guarantor.
2. if guarantor and owner is present result should be of the guarantor.
3. if the executive and owner is present result should be of the executive.

How can I do it? Please find my below result set.

```
PARENTID    RELATION_CODE   RELATION    PERCENTAGE
2628             101       Owner            14%
2628             101       Owner            14%
2628             101       Owner            14%
2628             101       Owner            14%
2628             201       Executive         0
2628             201       Executive         0
2628             201       Executive         0
2628             201       Executive         0
2628             301       Guarantor        17%
2628             301       Guarantor        17%
2628             301       Guarantor        17%
2628             301       Guarantor        17%
```

The expected result here is

```
PARENTID    RELATION_CODE   RELATION    PERCENTAGE
    2628             301       Guarantor        17%
    2628             301       Guarantor        17%
    2628             301       Guarantor        17%
    2628             301       Guarantor        17%
```

Comment: The first and second condition have the same result is that corrected?

Comment: @D-Shih..Yes, you are right...Guarantor has preference

Comment: Please check my answer I have also added data as per all the three conditions in the demo link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggravate function with a self join, then add logic in `where` clause

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM T t1 join
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN RELATION IN ('Owner','guarantor') THEN RELATION END) guarantorCnt,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN RELATION IN ('Owner','executive') THEN RELATION END) executiveCnt,
       PARENTID
FROM T 
GROUP BY PARENTID
) t2 on t1.PARENTID = t2.PARENTID
WHERE 
   (guarantorCnt = 2 AND t1.RELATION = 'guarantor') 
or
   (executiveCnt = 2 AND guarantorCnt < 2 AND t1.RELATION = 'executive')
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1a71e2f162181e3a5ae466fbc32aff23)

Comment: How can I use a table column value in SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN RELATION IN ('Owner','guarantor') THEN RELATION END) guarantorCnt. I have a table tab_relation which is having relation values in c_relation column. So need to change the above query as SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN RELATION IN (select c_relation from tab_relation where c_relaton>300 and c_relation<400) THEN RELATION END) guarantorCnt.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        PARENTID,
        RELATION,
        RELATION_CODE
        FROM YourTable
),C2
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        FROM CTE
        PIVOT
            (
                COUNT(RELATION_CODE)
                FOR
                RELATION IN
                (
                    [Owner],[Executive],[Guarantor]
                )
            )T
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM YourTable T
        WHERE EXISTS
        (
            SELECT
                1
                FROM C2
                    WHERE PARENTID = T.PARENTID
                        AND
                        (
                            (
                                [Guarantor] >0
                                AND 
                                T.RELATION = 'Guarantor'
                            )
                            OR
                            (
                                [Guarantor] =0
                                AND
                                (
                                    [Owner]>0
                                    AND 
                                    [Executive]>0
                                    AND 
                                    T.RELATION = 'Executive'
                                )
                            )
                        )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

With a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select distinct relation_code from t
)

select * from t
where 
  relation_code = 301
  and 
  (101 in (select * from cte) and 301 in (select * from cte))
union all 
select * from t
where 
  relation_code = 201
  and (
    (select count(*) from cte) = 2
    and
    (101 in (select * from cte) and 201 in (select * from cte))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using case statement and if exists as shown below.

```
Select * from #Temp3
where RELATION = 
(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM #Temp3
                   WHERE RELATION = 'Owner' AND EXISTS( SELECT 1
                   FROM #Temp3 WHERE RELATION = 'Executive' 
                   AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM #Temp3 WHERE RELATION = 'Guarantor'))) 
      THEN 'Guarantor' ELSE
      CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM  #Temp3
                   WHERE RELATION = 'Guarantor'
                   AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM #Temp3 WHERE RELATION = 'Owner')) THEN 'Guarantor' 
      ELSE CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM  #Temp3
                   WHERE RELATION = 'Executive'
                   AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM #Temp3 WHERE RELATION = 'Owner')) THEN 'Executive' 
      END END END)
```

You can find the live demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/RERZ56888).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to get the maximum `RELATION_CODE` for each `PARENTID`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.relation_code = (select t2.relation_code
                         from t t2
                         where t2.parentid = t.parentid
                        );
```